# Using C# language, if(NegativeValue < 0) returns 'false' rather 'true'

Tags: c#

Snippet : Calculating Discriminant (Disc) for a Quadratic Equation :

```
        Disc = Math.Sqrt((secondCoefficient * secondCoefficient) - (4 * firstCoefficient * thirdCoefficient));
        if (Disc < 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Its imaginary discriminant which can't be calculated!");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The Discriminant of the required quadratic equation is : " + Convert.ToString(Disc), "Discriminant Calculator");
        }
```

Output :
Disc = -Ve(Negative Value)
Display Text : The Discriminant of the required quadratic equation is : NaN
Would you please explain me in detail ? I tried of understanding but failed to get the right reason.

Question : If Disc value is negative then 'if' statement returns as 'false', while it should return as 'true'.

Comment: That isn't a question. It's also not true.

Comment: Why would the result of Math.Sqrt ever be negative? Hint: It won't be. It will be >= 0 or NaN.

Comment: What is your question? Also, can you provide values and types for the variables? Thanks

Comment: Can .net/mono Math.Sqrt() create negative values? :D

Comment: As I recall, the Disc is the part within the Sqrt, not the Sqrt itself.

Comment: @Ant P : Would you please tell me that how this is not a question as well as true ? While I am facing this problem right now.

Comment: Okay, well, it's not a question because... it's a statement. It's not true because if `Disc` is negative, `Disc < 0` returns true. So you must be mistaken about the value of `Disc` (which you are because `Math.Sqrt` return values will never be negative).

Comment: @user2864740 : Yes the discriminant value is NaN. Now I understand the reason. Thanks a lot for clarifications.

Comment: @Ant P : Exactly. I am sorry if I bothered by any means. Next time on I would take care of these mistakes. Thanks for your guidance as well as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of [`Math.Sqrt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.sqrt(v=vs.110).aspx) will *never* be negative: the result will will be >= 0, NaN, or +Inf.

Check the *actual* value of `Disc` after the evaluation.